# doubt on silicon naming or type

Tags: integrated-circuit

I always thought that the internal silicon inside ICs are called Dies(as in Silicon die). But I just stumbled upon a component from Linear Tech. It is the RH3845MK. The datasheet says DICE !!!
The screen shot is below and the datasheet is [Link](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/rh3845mkfa.pdf)

[image: Dice]
What is the difference between die and dice ?

Comment: "Die" is singular, and "Dice" is plural.

Comment: @NickJohnson That is actually an answer and not a comment. Maybe a better place would be English Language Stack Exchange for a more detailed analysis...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In (UK at least) English, there are two meanings for the noun die - a gaming piece with numbers on it, and a shaped piece of metal as a tool ( for cutting threads, casting or stamping ) and by extension shaped pieces of silicon.

The plural for the gaming piece is dice.

The plural for the shaped piece of metal is dies.

For silicon, it seems 'dice' is about twice as common as 'dies', but either can be used - see [this n-gram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=silicon%20dies%2Csilicon%20dice&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3)

Answer (score 1):

"Die" is the singular of "Dice".